# Commerce config page permissions

Tags: commerce

What permissions do commerce configuration page (path: `admin/commerce/config`) need to view as a position in menu? Asking, because I added link to this page in my custom menu and user with `access administration pages` permission don't see it. But... he can enter this page and see all it's content. Same thing with `admin/commerce` path.

I was clearing all caches too. Nothing helped.

Comment: Seems you are from Poland - Can you explain what you want in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers)? Because I can't understand it now... And in chat nobody will get too angry if you will end up using sentence or two in our language.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/134614/how-do-i-find-out-what-controls-access-to-a-page

Comment: @Letharion as we figured out in chat, these pages *are* accessible. Only hidden in menu.